# docker ps and docker images shows nothing but the services are running and available?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I know there are a bunch of similar questions on stackoverflow but my situation is quite different:

I have 2 containers running on a Google Cloud Platform VM. One is Prometheus and the other is Grafana. I am sure that the containers are up and running normally since I can visit the application on web browser. They have to be running well.

However, In the VM, `docker ps`, or `docker ps -a`, or even `docker images` shows nothing:

```
john@monitor:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
john@monitor:~$
```

and here:

```
john@monitor:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
```

and here:

```
john@monitor:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
john@monitor:~$
```

However, when I check the processes, I can see docker process running:

```
john@monitor:~$ ps aux| grep docker
root      8391  0.0  1.7 842188 66124 ?        Ssl  Jun10 194:16 dockerd --group docker --exec-root=/var/snap/docker/471/run/docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/var/snap/docker/471/run/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/471/config/daemon.json
root      8500  0.1  0.7 438932 29032 ?        Ssl  Jun10 379:58 containerd --config /var/snap/docker/471/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level error
root     22058  0.0  1.1 794352 42052 ?        Ssl   2019 207:18 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
tx-deep+ 26008  0.0  0.0  14852  1036 pts/1    S+   11:14   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
root     29899  0.0  0.0 378864   924 ?        Sl   Apr16   0:17 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9090 -container-ip 172.29.0.2 -container-port 9090
root     29906  0.0  0.0  10740  1648 ?        Sl   Apr16   6:34 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/65a898ec109fc2138afd480f7aeb0a7d2798f6771f8da4ffbbef9328c210c6a9 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
root     30030  0.0  0.0 458360  3048 ?        Sl   Apr16   4:40 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 3000 -container-ip 172.29.0.3 -container-port 3000
root     30038  0.0  0.0   9332  1544 ?        Sl   Apr16   9:15 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/20aee67a2c83843af634e9d7577bddbc831cbdff0b97011d4510d0a889d6d942 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
472      30057  0.4  1.1 154040 44164 ?        Ssl  Apr16 1218:42 grafana-server --homepath=/usr/share/grafana --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --packaging=docker cfg:default.log.mode=console cfg:default.paths.data=/var/lib/grafana cfg:default.paths.logs=/var/log/grafana cfg:default.paths.plugins=/var/lib/grafana/plugins cfg:default.paths.provisioning=/etc/grafana/provisioning
john@monitor:~$
```

You can see that there are docker-proxy service running on port 9090 and 3000, which are the prometheus and grafana containers.

What is going on?

Comment: How did you deploy the containers onto the GCE instance? Can you also run `docker info` to confirm nothing is reported by your `docker` commands. And finally have you tried running as root (`sudo -i`)

Comment: @Tanjin I deployed the containers through a docker-compose.yml with `restart: always` specified. I have tried `sudo docker ps -a` and `sudo docker images` and nothing showed up.

Answer (score 0):

I see grafana running as its own process:

```
472      30057  0.4  1.1 154040 44164 ?        Ssl  Apr16 1218:42 grafana-server --homepath=/usr/share/grafana --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --packaging=docker cfg:default.log.mode=console cfg:default.paths.data=/var/lib/grafana cfg:default.paths.logs=/var/log/grafana cfg:default.paths.plugins=/var/lib/grafana/plugins cfg:default.paths.provisioning=/etc/grafana/provisioning
```

I also see two runc processes. Docker has both a container build and runtime component. There is also ways to invoke a runtime engine besides docker as well.

So these two entries may be what your looking for:

```
root     29906  0.0  0.0  10740  1648 ?        Sl   Apr16   6:34 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/65a898ec109fc2138afd480f7aeb0a7d2798f6771f8da4ffbbef9328c210c6a9 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
```

```
root     29906  0.0  0.0  10740  1648 ?        Sl   Apr16   6:34 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/65a898ec109fc2138afd480f7aeb0a7d2798f6771f8da4ffbbef9328c210c6a9 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
```

They appear to be running as root not as your user.

I'm not sure how these processes were started (i.e. if thru docker or not)

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this [Prometheus + Grafana](https://royportas.com/posts/2020-02-25-prometheus-and-grafana-configuration-for-docker-compose/) docker-compose deployment in a [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os) VM with a [containerized docker-compose](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os), and `docker ps` seems to list its containers whether it was deployed from my user or `root` (with the container processes running as `root` either way).

If you have specific reproduction steps (eg. docker-compose deployment, Docker version, OS) I believe you should also share them in [this open bug in GitHub](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2201), as no one has been able to provide them yet.